# Does Google follow jQuery "click" window.open as if they were anchor links?

Tags: jquery, indexing, click, anchor

I have a click function that opens a new window instead of using an anchor tag with href attribute.  If I don't use an anchor tag, will google still crawl my page and index everything as if I did?

```
$(".link").click(function(){
var page_name  = (this.id);
var luw_window = window.open("/_www/more_info.php?page="+page_name,"luw_page", "left=1,top=1");
luw_window.focus();
return false;
});
```

Comment: in head tag use  `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` then google no index your page

Comment: that wasn't what I was asking.  I do want them to index the page. I am using onclick window.open instead of links and want to know if they will still follow those links and index those pages

Comment: crawlers are HIGHLY unlikely to execute javascript. e.g. consider `<a href="javascript:while(1);">`. oooops...no more crawler.

Comment: Use  `rel="nofollow"` eg: `<a href="url" rel="nofollow">link text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `rel="nofollow"`

Eg:

```
<a href="url" rel="nofollow">link text</a>
```